# Hiding/Disabling JQGrid checkboxes from specific users

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid within a form. The table itself is always visible to any user.  I'm using a custom JSTL tag to determine if the buttons (controls?) should be rendered or not.  For any user not in a specific role, I render the buttons, otherwise, users just see the table.

I'd like to be able to toggle the viability, or at a minimum the enabled state of the JQGrid check-box column. I assume I could just spit out some java script in the same tag that sets a variable to determine this, but I don't know if that is appropriate.

Is this possible? If so what is the appropriate way to accomplish it?

Note:  The hiding of the checkboxes would be purely for cosmetic reasons as the "submit" buttons would not be rendered, and there are other checks to see if a given user should be able to submit the data.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you mean. Which form you mean? Add/Edit form of form editing? Which hidden controls you mean? Where the control exist? Who creates the controls? Why should the controls be created on the page of unauthorized user? Every hidden control can made be visible using Developer Tools (press F12 to start). You speak about "check-box column" of jqGrid. How you create the grid? One can easy hide the column using `hideCol`. Much better would be don't send sensible information to the user at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning this so I may be off on my terminology, specifically hide vs rendered. I made some edits to try to be a bit more clear, hopefully this answers your questions.  In short, the decision to render the buttons or not are decided by the JSTL tag  class at compile time.